# How to upload video as multipart request using OkHTTP? [ Android ]

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I need to upload video to an API, and this is how I've implemented the OKHTTP request:

```
 private void makeRequest(Uri uri)
{
    pr1.show();

    try
    {
        String path = uri.toString();
        Log.e("PATH",path);
        File file = new File(new URI(path));
        try {

            RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                    .addFormDataPart("file", file.getName(),
                            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("video/mp4"), file))
                    .addFormDataPart("title", "damn")
                    .build();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(URL)
                    .header("SproutVideo-Api-Key","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
                    .post(requestBody)
                    .build();

            client.newCall(request)
                    .enqueue(new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(final Call call, IOException e)
                        {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                            String res = response.body().string();
                            Log.e("SUCCESS",""+res);
                            pr1.dismiss();


                        }
                    });


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Handle the error
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){}

}
```

However, I am unable to complete a successful request.

Log at this line `Log.e("PATH",path);` shows :

> content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A75611

And when I add a line break at this line : `client.newCall(request)`, and run the debugger, the app doesn't end at any point, so I assume the request is not getting completed. What is possibly causing this? Is this the correct way of implementation?

Comment: I would try to debug with `execute()` in place of `enqueue()`.

Comment: what difference does it make? Kindly let me know what `execute()` does instead of `enqueue()` !

Comment: Are you shure about the protocol `content://` ? I would expect `http://` here.

Comment: it is URI .................

Comment: You want to use this [api](http://sproutvideo.com/docs/api.html) ?

Comment: nope, I am uploading to this URL : `https://api.sproutvideo.com/v1/videos` as POST, the Uri is what I obtained when I picked the video using file picker in Android

Comment: `what difference does it make?`, maybe the debugger won't branch into the new thread. By using `execute()`  the debugger (and the exception, if any) may gives more info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the OkHTTP library, but one thing I noticed that will cause a problem is that the field for the video should be `source_video`, not `file` [as outlined here](http://sproutvideo.com/docs/api.html#Uploadanewvideo).

You might also want to add some logging to your catch statements to see what, if anything might be failing silently since you seem to be ignoring any potential failures.